# Creating a Tri-Color faced cube in openGL

Tags: opengl

I am trying to create a cube in opengl which has faces as tricolors(like some flag). There should be only one cube, but the top 1/3rd should be red, middle 1/3rd should be blue and bottom 1/3rd should be green. I can make the faces of one color by putting a single color to a face. or the face can be made colorful by putting color corresponding to each vertex. But How to exactly trisect it, I have no idea.

Comment: just add some more vertices and use vertex colour, or map a suitable texture over the whole face.

Comment: or you can do the color assignment in fragment shader, based on the fragment's "height" coordinate value in model space... This way you dont need to change the geometry.